Create AWS CloudWatch Alarm based on new Metric (before data points)
I have created an AWS CloudWatch metric that will filter events based on a warning condition from my Lambda. The condition is going to happen rarely and there is not a way for me to 'falsely trigger it' for testing purposes.
I would like to create a CloudWatch Alarm based on the newly created Metric. However, it seems that it is not possible via the AWS console to do this until I have at least 1 data point for the Metric, i.e. at least one Lambda invocation where the rare condition has been met.
I realize I can get around this via e.g. the AWS CLI or CloudFormation, but I am trying to guide other users in how they can set this up via the AWS console alone.
Is there really no way to achieve this?

You are correct -- the management console creates alarms by example, so it needs the metric to exist. You can use the AWS CLI to send a metric to CloudWatch and then you could use the management console to create the alarm, but if you are wanting to avoid the AWS CLI then it's not possible.
